# how to push to a controller array from a factory? or execute a controller function from factory

Tags: angularjs

I am writing a chat application in cordova that receives push notifications.

Upon receiving a message, I check if the user is currently on the chat page. If he is, I want to make a call to my server to update the array that displays messages.

My push functions are in a factory and when a push comes in, it executes `onNotification`

My problem is that I can't access the `$scope.messages` array in my controller to push the new message. I've tried adding $scope to my factory but that didn't work.

How do I access or push to an array that exists in my controller from a factory?

Edit: Just realized an alternative. Is there a way for a factory to execute a function in the controller? I could also accomplish what I need if this was possible

Note: `onNotification` is a plugin from cordova that is called when a notification is received. I can't pass anything into onNotification.

Here's the essential/pseudo bits of code I currently have.

Chat controller

```
.controller('ChatCtrl',function($scope, ...etc){
    $scope.messages = [];
}
```

Factory

```
.factory('PushService'['$http',function($http){

   onNotification: function(e){

         $http.get('my_server_url')
         .success(function(data){
              // HERE I want to add the new data to $scope.messages from my controller, 
              // but I don't know how to access $scope.messages
              // Alternatively, if it's possible to execute a function in my controller 
             // from this factory that would work as well
         })
         .error(function(data){ //handle error});

   }
}]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not usual to do it the way round you try, because the Factory is most likely going to live throughout the entire application lifecycle (until the browser tab is closed), whereas the controller won't. A controller gets normally destroyed when the route changes. So the factory would not be able to rely upon the controller to exist...

The Angular way of doing this would be to create the messages array within the factory, where it lives. Then you inject the factory into the controller, where you can access it and there you can also assign the messages array to the `$scope`.

**Example using your code:**

Controller

```
.controller('ChatCtrl',function($scope, PushService){
    $scope.messages = PushService.messages;
});
```

Factory

```
.factory('PushService'['$http',function($http){

  return {

    messages: [],

    onNotification: function(e){

      var messages = this.messages;  

      $http.get('my_server_url')
      .success(function(data){

        messages.push({ ... })

      })
      .error(function(data){ //handle error});
    }

  };

}]);
```

Another alternative would be to use Angular's event broadcasting mechanism. For example the factory could `$rootScope.$broadcast` a message to your controller, who would receive it with `$scope.$on`. This however is not really recommended, because `$broadcast` will broadcast the message to **all** of your scopes, which is not very efficient (esp. with messages in a chat application).

Comment: Thanks for the response. One more thing though, in my http call, I set a `$scope.variable` to a value and this would display in the view. Now when I moved this to the factory, even if I use `$scope.myvariable = PushService.myvariable;` in the controller and var `myvariable = this.myvariable` in the factory, it is not displaying in the view when I use `{{myvariable}}`. Why/what can I do about this?

Comment: It seems that you pass the variable by value and not by reference. Therefore it is not updated. Instead of passing a string like `$scope.myString=PushService.myString`you need to wrap it in an object (objects and arrays are always passed by reference). So do `$scope.obj=PushService.obj` whereas `PushService.obj` is `{ myString: 'abc' }`

Comment: That's exactly the problem! Forgot about primitive data types I just fixed it and it's working thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you call onNotification in controller, can you simply pass $scope to onNotification?

Answer (score 0):

I changed few code for service doing addition? I hope this would work.

I used $q and promise to get existing items if there are any in factory.

```
app.factory('PushService', ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {
    var messages = [];
    return {
        GetMessages: function (e) {

                var deferred = $q.defer();
                if (messages.length == 0) {
                    $http.get('my_server_url')
                        .success(function (data) {
                        //HERE I want to add the new data to $scope.messages from my controller, but I don't know how to access $scope.messages
                        messages = data.messages;
                             deferred.resolve(data.messages);
                    })
                        .error(function (data) { //handle error});
                    });
                } else {
                     deferred.resolve(messages);
                }

                return deferred.promise;

        },

        AddMessage: function (message) {
            messages.push(message);
        }
    };
}]);

app.controller('ChatCtrl',function($scope, PushService){
    PushService.GetMessages().then(function(data) {
        $scope.messages = data;
        $scope.OnNotification = function(messageToAdd){
          PushService.AddMessage(messageToAdd);  
        };
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want continuously push data from factory to controller, you can do that by rising a event. please see here : http://plnkr.co/edit/94BDUno9BmbcphABV6jl
in your case it will be something like:

**factory:**

```
.factory('PushService'['$http',' $rootScope',function($http){

   onNotification: function(e){

         $http.get('my_server_url')
         .success(function(data){
              //rise the event

          $rootScope.$broadcast('newMessage', data)
         })
         .error(function(data){ //handle error});

   }
}]);
```

**controller:**

```
.controller('ChatCtrl',function($scope, ...etc){
    $scope.messages = [];

 $scope.$on('newMessage', function(event, data) {
    $scope.messages.push(data); // 'Data to send'
  });
```

}